# Using vim's command-t within rails projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I'm a big fan of tpope's rails.vim but I find the default search mechanism's autocomplete to be a pain in the ass.

At the same time I've found command-t's fuzzy search to be awesome and faster than going `:RTcontroller a<TAB><TAB><TAB>`.

However, it defaults to searching within the same directory of my currently open file which is less than useful.

Is there a good way to get command-t to begin searching at the root of my rails project whenever I open a file within it? Going :cd ../../ before opening up command-t almost seems to make its use moot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Command-T, but I'd assume it has no project-awareness. However, rails.vim does, and you can probably use the buffer-local rails_root variable to focus search:

`:exe "CommandT" b:rails_root`

Comment: Can you provide a syntax example on how to do buffer-local rails_root variable leaning?

Comment: Probably because it's named after a feature of a commercial/non-free application (TextMate)? It doesn't offend me, but I agree the name is an unfortunate choice.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same need; it seems that Command-T cannot find files in parent or sibling directories.

Luckily I found ctrlp at https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim, which works as desired and runs very smoothly. Besides, installation is a snap if you happen to use [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) and ctrlp works out of the box. It doesn't depend on Ruby as Command-T does.